# VirtualBox Teleportation (VM migration) error: failed to load unit 'cpum'

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm making a Vbox teleportation application for VM migration between two similar Dell machines on the same subnet.

The source is an ubuntu 14.04 VM that needs to be teleported to client Dell server which is hosting an unbooted VM with a harddisk .vdi on a nfs-shared folder with the original VM.

When the teleportation is initiated, the process reaches 90% and then exits with the following error:
VBoxManage: error: Teleportation failed 
VBoxManage: error: Failed to load unit 'cpum' (VERR_INVALID_FLAGS)
.
.
.

I looked up online and found just one relevant reply to a similar query. So I typed the following command at the client end.
VBoxManage setextradata vm_name VBoxInternal/CPUM/CMPXCHG16B 1

Still the problem persists.

Please advise

Answer (score 4):

One of my VMs came up with the same error. I wasn't doing anything with teleporting, but the VM was in a "saved state". Discarding the saved state resolved the matter.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I haven't found a solution, but a reasonable workaround:
I've told VirtualBox to discard the saved machine state, and then restarted it.